# bash string compare between 2 csv files

Tags: string, bash, csv, compare

I have two strings (parsed from csv) which has ~200 columns each. I need to compare them and identify which column is different. Example:

```
str1file1="a,b,c,d,e,f,pp,qq"
str2file2="a,b,c,d,x,f,pp,qq"
```

I need to get column number as 5 and corresponding values as my output. Example: 5 e f
As I need to compare millions of such strings, speed is the key. Actual record -

```
0x0009aeef,xyz,wert,57116,192.168.17.1,45320,192.168.17.2,45320,ctty,lkipop,1408477403,1408477403,,1408477722,1408477403,1408477718,2,0,5,98,0,3055925732,0,0,0,0,15756,15732,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.68,23,0,1,23,15776,0.00,15270,459,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5.755,1408477403,1408477718,2,0,7,98,0,112988428,0,0,0,0,15776,15742,34,0,0,0,0,0,0,8.32,33,0,1,33,15756,0.01,15555,185,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3.077,-0,-0,-12,-11,-23,-36,-31,-39,22,35,19,28,,,,,1.8,2.4,2.2,2.6,1.8,2.4,2.2,2.5,37,49,45,52,36,48,44,51,15625,107,891,5.60,12528,3204,14430,1312,723,2.65,13291,2451
```

0x0009aeef is a primary key/column (1st col), however it's not assured that both file has identical number of entries (rows). I'm using sort wrt primary key and get required columns (~135) using cut creating temp files . 
Followed by 'while read' to read 1st temp file and grep to get matching lines on temp2 file.
If grep fails, chances are key or values are different. Hence awk for key and values. Any better approach much appreciated. Here is present code -

```
sort --field-separator=',' --key=1 $csv1 | cut -d "," -f1,...134 | tr -d '\t' > file1
sort --field-separator=',' --key=1 $csv2 | cut -d "," -f1,...134 | tr -d '\t' > file2
while read line; do
      sl=`grep "$line" file2`
      if [ "$line" != "$sl" ]; then
         rec=`echo $line | awk -F, '{ print $1 }'`
         slId=`grep $rec file2 | awk -F, '{ print $1 }'`
         if [ "$rec" = "$slId" ]; then
               #validation failed, primary key found
         else
               #prim key not found
        fi
     else
        #all is well
     fi
done < file1
```

Comment: One record in 1 file,1st col primary key -0x0009aeef,sbcd,qwer,57116,192.168.17.1,45320,192.168.17.2,45320,12345,tyuio,1408477403,1408477403,,1408477722,1408477403,1408477718,2,0,5,98,0,3055925732,0,0,0,0,15756,15732,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.68,23,0,1,23,15776,0.00,15270,459,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5.755,1408477403,1408477718,2,0,7,98,0,112988428,0,0,0,0,15776,15742,34,0,0,0,0,0,0,8.32,33,0,1,33,15756,0.01,15555,185,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3.077,-0,-0,-12,-11,-23,-36,-31,-39,22,35,19,28,,,,,1.8,2.4,2.2,2.6,1.8,2.4,2.2,2.5,37,49,45,52,36,48,44,51,15625,107,891,5.60,12528,3204,14430,1312,723,2.65,13291,2451

Comment: It's best to edit your post with this info.  Putting code in comment format makes it hard to read.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for info on how to properly format input/output file text (code).  Also, in order to get a complete solution, we'd need samples of the unparsed file, a description of the desired output, sample desired output, and the code you're currently using.  Since the lines of the file are so long, you can provide shorter examples that represent the file conceptually.  Using a read loop and pipes with `grep`, `awk`, `sort`, and `cut` will undoubtedly be quite slow.

Comment: I'm assuming there's a typo in setting the `s1` variable to `grep` for `file1` instead of `file2`.  Otherwise you'd just be creating a duplicate variable and running an unnecessary `grep` process.

Comment: yes, it's a typo, rectified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If speed is the key, I'd consider parsing the CSV files using `mawk` or update the post with file examples so we can offer a better solution.

Using Bash:

```
IFS=, read -a line <<<"$str1"
IFS=, read -a line2 <<<"$str2"
for i in ${!line[@]}; do
    if [[ ${line[i]} != ${line2[i]} ]]; then
        echo -e "${line[i]}\n${line2[i]}"
    fi
done
```

Output:

```
e
x
```